# How to debug this code for left-rotation of an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have written code for single step left rotation but during the code arr is taking a garbage value, I am unable to understand why?

```
arrlen,rotid =  [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
arr = [int(arr_temp) for arr_temp in input().strip().split(' ')]
arrnew = arr

while(rotid>0):
    for i in range(0,arrlen):
        if(i==0):
            arrnew[arrlen-1] = arr[0]

        else:
            arrnew[i-1] = arr[i]

    arr = arrnew
    print(arr)
    rotid =  rotid-1

arr1 = " ".join(str(xx) for xx in arrnew)
print(arr1)
```

Comment: What should we type for those `input` calls?

Comment: `arrnew = arr` doesn't make a copy of `arr`.

Comment: Yeah, I made the change, still it's giving garbage value.

Comment: @Kevin - you can give length of array and number of rotation in a single line with single space and in the second line you can give array with single space.

Answer (score 0):

The way variables and assignment works in Python, setting a variable to the value of some mutable object will by default simply make the variable point to the same instance of the object. So when you set `arrnew = arr` in your code, you are actually setting `arrnew` to be a reference to `arr`, which is causing you to read from and write to the same list. To fix it, change that line to:

```
arrnew = arr[:]
```

which is a Python idiom to copy a list (basically, it takes a slice of the whole list, and slices are always made into new objects).